# Create bootable OVF image using root filesystem folder from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, build-automation, vsphere, rootfs, ovf

I'd like to ask if there is a way to create OVF images using the Linux command line from a specific folder. This folder would contain a Linux root file system. The generated OVF files would later be imported into VSPhere and they need to be able to boot. I need a way, so that I can automate the creation of these artifacts.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hey! I think you've got the wrong forum for this question, this seems more suited for [Superuser.](https://superuser.com/) Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll ask the question there.